# How do i create a mock for this Role Service

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, observable, karma-jasmine

Role Service is part of our Application.
I am not able to use this service as I am not able to mock BehaviourSubjects

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ConstantService } from '../../services/constant/constant.service';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class RoleService {

  constants; // Variable to hold the constant JSON in asset folder

  constructor(private constantService: ConstantService) {
    this.constants = this.constantService.constantJson();
  }

  private isSiteAdmin = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);
  public isSiteAdmin$ = this.isSiteAdmin.asObservable();

  private isPolicyApprover = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);
  public isPolicyApprover$ = this.isPolicyApprover.asObservable();

  private isFtpApprover = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);
  public isFtpApprover$ = this.isFtpApprover.asObservable();

  resetRoles() {
    this.isSiteAdmin.next(false);
    this.isPolicyApprover.next(false);
    this.isFtpApprover.next(false);
  }

  setUserRoles() {

    this.resetRoles();

    const roleList = this.constants.Roles;
    let userDetails;
    if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser') !== undefined) {
      userDetails = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    }

    if (userDetails.Roles.length > 0) {
      userDetails.Roles.forEach(role => {
        switch (role.RoleId) {
          case roleList.site_admin:
            this.isSiteAdmin.next(true);
            break;
          case roleList.policy_approver:
            this.isPolicyApprover.next(true);
            break;
          case roleList.ftp_approver:
            this.isFtpApprover.next(true);
            break;
          default:
            this.isUser.next(true);
        }
      });
    }
  }

}
```

It reports a error Failed: roleService.isSiteAdmin$ is undefined
How do I create a mock for this Service so that i can use it in components

**SPEC FILE of MAIN PAGE COMPONENT**

```
let component: MainPageComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<MainPageComponent>;

fdescribe('MainPageComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        MainPageComponent,
        ControlLabelComponent,
        ControlTextboxComponent,
        ControlTextEditorComponent,
        ControlDropdownComponent,
        ControlUploadComponent,
        ControlImageViewerComponent,
        ControlHeaderComponent,
        ControlSubHeaderComponent,
        ControlMultilineBoxComponent,
        ControlExternalLinkerComponent,
        ControlLinkRepeaterComponent,
        ControlSyncAssociationComponent,
        ControlActorSubheaderComponent,
        LockContextComponent,
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: Http, deps: [MockBackend] },
        { provide: ConstantService, useClass: ConstantServiceMock },
        { provide: LeftPanelService, useClass: ConstantServiceMock },
        { provide: RoleService, useClass: RoleServiceMock },
        { provide: MenuService, useClass: MenuService },
      ],
      imports: [
        HttpClientModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
        FormsModule,
        ModalModule.forRoot()
      ],
      schemas: [
          NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA,
          CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MainPageComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  }));

  it('should create the app', () => {
    // component.constants.environment.production = true;
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Same it is again saying roleService.isSiteAdmin$ is undefined.

**ADDED TS FILE for better understanding**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ConstantService } from '../../services/constant/constant.service';
import { LeftPanelService } from '../../services/left-panel/left-panel.service';
import { RoleService } from '../../services/role/role.service';
import { MenuService } from '../../services/menu/menu.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'main-page',
  templateUrl: './main-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main-page.component.css']
})
export class MainPageComponent implements OnInit {

  //#region VARIABLES

  //#region Role Variables
  isSiteAdmin;
  isUser;
  isEditor;
  isProjectApprover;
  isAdmin;
  isUsecaseApprover;
  isActorApprover;
  isScenarioApprover;
  isPolicyApprover;
  isFtpApprover;

  isOtherMenuOptionDisabled;
  //#endregion

  messages; // Variable to hold the message JSON in asset folder
  constants; // Variable to hold the constant JSON in asset folder
  successPopupMessage: string; // used to show success message
  @ViewChild('successPopup') successPopup;
  errorPopupMessage: string; // used to show error message
  @ViewChild('errorPopup') errorPopup;
  @ViewChild('rightPanel') rightPanel;
  @ViewChild('whoApproved') whoApprovedPopup;
  @ViewChild('lockedInEditViewChild') lockedInEditViewChild;
  mainPageMenu;

  whoApprovedData;
  whoApprovedModalPopup;

  lockedInEditDataString: string;
  lockedInEditDataModalPopup;
  //#endregion

  //#region Constructor
  constructor(private constantService: ConstantService,
    private leftPanelService: LeftPanelService,
    public roleService: RoleService,
    private menuService: MenuService) {
    this.messages = this.constantService.messageJson();
    this.constants = this.constantService.constantJson();

    // get options
    menuService.mainPageMenu$.subscribe(menu => {
      this.mainPageMenu = menu;
    });

    // set the roles - added in the mail page constructor so that the values are available even if the page is refreshed
    this.roleService.setUserRoles();

    // set options
    this.menuService.setMainMenuOption();

    this.initializeMainPageMenu();

     // check site admin
     roleService.isSiteAdmin$.subscribe(isSiteAdmin => {
      this.isSiteAdmin = isSiteAdmin;
    });

    // check editor
    roleService.isEditor$.subscribe(isEditor => {
      this.isEditor = isEditor;
    });

    // check isUser
    roleService.isUser$.subscribe(isUser => {
      this.isUser = isUser;
    });

    // check isProjectApprover
    roleService.isProjectApprover$.subscribe(isProjectApprover => {
      this.isProjectApprover = isProjectApprover;
    });

    // check isUsecaseApprover
    roleService.isUsecaseApprover$.subscribe(isUsecaseApprover => {
      this.isUsecaseApprover = isUsecaseApprover;
    });

    // check isActorApprover
    roleService.isActorApprover$.subscribe(isActorApprover => {
      this.isActorApprover = isActorApprover;
    });

    // check isScenarioApprover
    roleService.isScenarioApprover$.subscribe(isScenarioApprover => {
      this.isScenarioApprover = isScenarioApprover;
    });

    // check isPolicyApprover
    roleService.isPolicyApprover$.subscribe(isPolicyApprover => {
      this.isPolicyApprover = isPolicyApprover;
    });

    // check isFtpApprover
    roleService.isFtpApprover$.subscribe(isFtpApprover => {
      this.isFtpApprover = isFtpApprover;
    });

    // check isAdmin
    roleService.isAdmin$.subscribe(isAdmin => {
      this.isAdmin = isAdmin;
    });

    this.disableOtherMenuOption();
    this.disableMenuForRoles();

    // who approved Modal Pop Up
    this.whoApprovedModalPopup = {
      whoApprovedModal: false,
      title: this.messages.LockPopup.WhoApproved,
      footerButtons: [
        { Text: 'Ok', event: 'ok', cssClass: 'footer-modal-popup-ok' },
      ],
    };

    // lock timeout Modal Pop Up
    this.lockedInEditDataModalPopup = {
      lockedInEditDataModal: false,
      title: this.messages.LockPopup.LockedInEditDetails,
      footerButtons: [
        { Text: 'Ok', event: 'ok', cssClass: 'footer-modal-popup-ok' },
      ],
    };
  }

  disableOtherMenuOption() {
    if (this.isSiteAdmin || this.isEditor) {
      this.isOtherMenuOptionDisabled = false;
    } else if (this.isUser || this.isProjectApprover || this.isScenarioApprover || this.isActorApprover
      || this.isUsecaseApprover || this.isPolicyApprover || this.isFtpApprover || this.isAdmin) {
      this.isOtherMenuOptionDisabled = true;
    }
  }
  //#endregion

  /**
   * Method to initialize Main Page Menu Options
   */
  initializeMainPageMenu() {
    // this.mainPageMenu = this.menuService.getMainPageMenu();

    /**
     * Method to disable all the remaining options other than view and create from FrameObject Menu
     */
    this.leftPanelService.getCurrentFrameObjType().subscribe(type => {
      this.mainPageMenu.dropdowns.forEach(dropDown => {
        if (dropDown.type !== type) {
          dropDown.options.forEach(option => {
            if (this.isOtherMenuOptionDisabled) {
              this.disabledExceptViewFrameObj(option);
            } else {
              if (option.key.indexOf('view') > -1 || option.key.indexOf('create') > -1) {
                option.isDisabled = false;
              } else {
                option.isDisabled = true;
              }
            }
          });
        } else {
          dropDown.options.forEach(option => {
            if (this.isOtherMenuOptionDisabled) {
              this.disabledExceptViewFrameObj(option);
            } else {
              option.isDisabled = false;
            }
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }

  disabledExceptViewFrameObj(option) {
    if (option.key.indexOf('view') > -1) {
      option.isDisabled = false;
    } else {
      option.isDisabled = true;
    }
  }

  disableMenuForRoles() {
    this.mainPageMenu.dropdowns.forEach(dropDown => {
      dropDown.options.forEach(option => {
        if (option.key.indexOf('view') > -1) {
          option.isDisabled = false;
        } else {
          if (this.isUser) {
            option.isDisabled = true;
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }
  //#endregion

  //#region Init
  ngOnInit() { }
  //#endregion

  /**
    * Method to hide the who approved pop up
    */
  okWhoApprovedModalPopup() {
    this.whoApprovedPopup.hide();
  }

  /**
    * Method to hide the lock time out pop up
    */
  okLockedInEditDataModalPopup() {
    this.lockedInEditViewChild.hide();
  }

}
```

In our application most of the places role services is used.
So if one page is solved..other will become easy.
Please look into it

Comment: please include the file where your error occurs when you call roleService.isSiteAdmin$

Comment: It is in spec file.

Comment: { provide: RoleService, useClass: 'MOCKFILEHERE'}, i should put the mock file here, but im not able to get what i should write mock for Subjects

Answer (score 0):

Create a mock class into your spec file :

```
class MockRoleService {
 // include any properties AND/OR functions used by the components
 isSiteAdmin$: Observable<boolean>;
 resetRoles() {}
 setUserRoles() {}
 ...
}
```

Declare your mocked service in the spec file providers :

`{ provide: RoleService, useClass: MockRoleService }`

Comment: nope it is still not able to set the value of isSiteAdmin$ undefined

Comment: please include the spec file

Comment: added spec file of the component in which this server is injected

Comment: Can you include the  component html/ts too please to understand how you call your service?

Comment: added the ts file too boss

Comment: not sure if it'll help with the test but you shouldn't put any logic into the constructor of your component as you are trying to interact with it whereas it's building itself. You should put it into the ngOnInit lifecycle hook. Give it a try because it might explain that the roleService is undefined at the point your are trying to call it.

Comment: yes that is the point ill put forward to my team..anyway thanks for the help